# SimpleInjector.DiagnosticVerificationException

Tags: c#

First of all sorry for so much code but i belive it will be easier to find an issue here. I am using SimpleInjector and getting error inside Program class on `container.Verify();` line, it says as below. I was trying to investigate throug docs website but still cannot figoure out how to fix that.

> SimpleInjector.DiagnosticVerificationException: 'The configuration is
>   invalid. The following diagnostic warnings were reported:
>   -[Disposable Transient Component] FrmLogin is registered as transient, but implements IDisposable. See the Error property for detailed
>   information about the warnings. Please see
>   https://simpleinjector.org/diagnostics how to fix problems and how to
>   suppress individual warnings.'

**Full code:**

```
static class Program
    {
        private static Container container;

        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        private static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Bootstrap();
            Application.Run(container.GetInstance<FrmLogin>());
        }

        private static void Bootstrap()
        {
            // Create the container as usual.
            container = new Container();   
            container.Register<IRepositoryDal<User>, UserRepositoryDal>();
            container.Register<IRepositoryDal<Order>, OrderRepositoryDal>();
            container.Register<IDbManager>(() => new DbManager("sqlserver"));
            container.Register<IGenericBal<User>, UserBal>();
            container.Register<IGenericBal<Order>, OrderBal>();
            container.Register<FrmLogin>();
            container.Verify();
        }
    }

    public partial class FrmLogin : Form
    {
        private readonly IGenericBal<User> _userBal;
        private readonly IGenericBal<Order> _orderBal;

        public FrmLogin(IGenericBal<User> userBal, IGenericBal<Order> orderBal)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            _userBal = userBal;
            _orderBal = orderBal;
}
}

    public interface IGenericBal<out T> where T : IEntity
    {
        IEnumerable<T> SearchByName(string name);
    }

    public class UserBal : IGenericBal<User>
    {
        private readonly IRepositoryDal<User> _userRepositoryDal;

        public UserBal(IRepositoryDal<User> userRepositoryDal)
        {
            _userRepositoryDal = userRepositoryDal ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(userRepositoryDal));
        }

        public IEnumerable<User> SearchByName(string name)
        {
               return _userRepositoryDal.SearchByName(name);
        }
    }

    public interface IEntity
    {
        int Id { get; set; }
        int DoSomething(string one, int two);
    }

    public interface IRepositoryDal<T> where T : IEntity
    {
        IEnumerable<T> SearchByName(string username);
        T SearchById(string id);
        void Update(T entity);
        void Remove(T entity);
        void Add(T entity);
    }

    public class UserRepositoryDal: IRepositoryDal<User>
    {
        private readonly IDbManager _dbManager;

        public UserRepositoryDal(IDbManager dbManager)
        {
            //read from either singleton or configuration file !!
            _dbManager = dbManager;
        }
        public IEnumerable<User> SearchByName(string username)
        {


                var parameters = new List<IDbDataParameter>
                {
                    _dbManager.CreateParameter("@Name", 50, username, DbType.String),
                };

            username = "JUSTyou";
            var userDataTable = _dbManager.GetDataTable("SELECT * FROM T_Marke WHERE Name=@Name", CommandType.Text, parameters.ToArray());

            foreach (DataRow dr in userDataTable.Rows)
            {
                var user = new User
                {
                    Id = int.Parse(dr["Id"].ToString()),
                    Firstname = dr["Name"].ToString(),
                };

                yield return user;
            }

        }
        public User SearchById(string id)
        {
            var parameters = new List<IDbDataParameter>
            {
                _dbManager.CreateParameter("@Id", 50, id, DbType.Int32),
            };

            var userDataTable = _dbManager.GetDataTable("storedpr2", CommandType.StoredProcedure, parameters.ToArray());

            return new User
            {
                Id = int.Parse(userDataTable.Rows[0]["Id"].ToString()),
                Firstname = userDataTable.Rows[0]["Firstname"].ToString(),
                Lastname = userDataTable.Rows[0]["LastName"].ToString(),
                Email = userDataTable.Rows[0]["Email"].ToString()
            };
        }

        public void Update(User entity)
        {
            throw new System.NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void Remove(User entity)
        {
            throw new System.NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void Add(User entity)
        {
            throw new System.NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    public class User : IEntity
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int DoSomething(string one, int two)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public string Firstname { get; set; }
        public string Lastname { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is quite clear

A registration has been made with the *Transient* *LifeStyle* for a component that implements `IDisposable`.

A component that implements `IDisposable` would usually need deterministic clean-up but *Simple Injector* does not implicitly track and dispose components registered with the transient lifestyle.

One way to fix this is to make its *Life Style* `Scoped`

```
var container = new Container();
// Select the scoped lifestyle that is appropriate for the application
// you are building. For instance:
container.Options.DefaultScopedLifestyle = new AsyncScopedLifestyle();

// DisposableService implements IDisposable
container.Register<FrmLogin>(Lifestyle.Scoped);
```

Since this is the main form you could probably ignore this warning
and dispose of it your self.

```
Registration registration = container.GetRegistration(typeof(FrmLogin)).Registration;

registration.SuppressDiagnosticWarning(DiagnosticType.DisposableTransientComponent,
    "Reason of suppression");
```

Though in my personal opinion, you should probably just give it the right *Life Style* and let *Simple Iinjector* take care of things

**Additional Resources**

[Diagnostic Warning - Disposable Transient Components](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/disposabletransientcomponent.html)

Comment: I did but then i get this error: "SimpleInjector.DiagnosticVerificationException: 'The configuration is invalid. The following diagnostic warnings were reported:
-[Lifestyle Mismatch] FrmLogin (Async Scoped) depends on IGenericBal<User> implemented by UserBal (Transient).
-[Lifestyle Mismatch] FrmLogin (Async Scoped) depends on IGenericBal<Order> implemented by OrderBal (Transient).
See the Error property for detailed information about the warnings. Please see https://simpleinjector.org/diagnostics how to fix problems and how to suppress individual warnings.'
"

Comment: @Arie yes I expected as muxh you are either going to have appropriately adjust the scope of all of its dependencies, or ignore the warning and dispose the form after run

Comment: what should i do? I did what you wrote and have above issue.